# How to solve an optimization problem with absolute constraint?

Tags: optimization

The optimization problem is shown below

$$
\min_{\boldsymbol{w}}\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{Sw}\\
s.t. |\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i|>1, i=1,2,\cdots, n
$$
, where $\boldsymbol{w}, \boldsymbol{a}_i$ are vectors and $\boldsymbol{S}$ is a positive-definite matrix.

The objective function is convex, but the feasible region defined by constraints is non-convex. Would any one provide some methods or insights in solving this optimization problem? Thanks.

============================================

All $\boldsymbol{a}_i$s are known. Also $\boldsymbol{S}_w$ is available.

I tried to convert the absolute inequality constraint $|\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i|>1$ to two constraints as follows:

$\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i>1$ and $\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i<-1$.

Unfortunately, we could not use these two constraints simultaneously, because these two constraints contradict to each other. We can only pick one of them. In this case, we need to pick one constraint from each absolute constraint, either $\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i>1$ or $\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i<-1$. This is a combination problem, where there are $2^n$ cases, which is not practical.

Comment: To get access to a greater pool of experts on optimization, consider posting this on some other site (one where optimization is more central a topic) of the Stack Exchange network instead.

Comment: Hi: Assuming the $a_i$ are known,  you can convert that to $w^{T} a_{i} > 1$ and $w^{T} a_{i} < -1$

Comment: @markleeds Depending on how $a_{i}$ is set, that might lead to discontinuities. Would that be an issue? The typical way that I have handled absolute value constraints is by adding in supplemental variables $w_{+}$ and $w_{-}$ with the property that if you subtract them you get $w$ and are both greater than zero individually. The only thing to be aware of is when $w_{+,i}$ and $w_{-,i}$ are both larger than zero. Adjusting the way the optimization is set up can help reduce the likelihood that happens.

Comment: @John: It's been a loooong time, as in multiple decades, since I took a class in optimization. You could be right but I'm not familiar with discontinuities in constraints causing a problem. Or it's possible that I just don't remember !!!!  Also, maybe your idea of using  $w_{-}$ and $w_{+}$ can help but, if I was andy, I would try seperating the constraint into the two constraints and then see if the result respects the constraints. Apologies for not being able to reply with a more useful response.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks for your advice. Is there website that recommend? Thanks again.

Comment: @markleeds thanks for your suggestions. I edit the question. I think convert $|\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i|>1$ to $\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i>1$ and $\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{a}_i<-1$ does not solve the issue, because these two new constraints contradict to each other.

Comment: @Andy, if I knew exactly, I would have given the title. But it should not be difficult to find out.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thank you.

Comment: @Andy: You're right that they contradict each other. My mistake. I'm not sure what I was thinking about that one that one. Yikes. Maybe that's why John offered his approach. Let me think about it a little or look on the net because now you've got me hooked a little bit. It's totally not my field so I doubt I can help and I'm sorry for the wrong comment. I'm gonna google for something and see if anything useful comes back.

Comment: Hi Andy: I definitely was messing up but I found below. you can modify your constraint to a less than by multiplying it by -1 on both sides and then use what they have in the link under absolute values in the constraints section.  I think that should work. Hopefully I won't go  2 for 2 in wrong advice . good luck. https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Optimization_with_absolute_values

Comment: @Andy You might also find the following answer useful: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33478/minimize-overall-portfolio-turnover-under-constraints

Comment: @John thanks a lot. : -)